# C# - Asp.net web API test project - how to impersonate a user and run test cases under a specific user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mstest, impersonation

I am working on ASP.net Web api project. I have added a test project. Inside one of the test case, I connect to SQL server using windows authentication. The test case works fine locally when I run it on Visual Studio as my account (my NT ID) is entitled to the SQL server.

But when we run the same test case on our build server, the test case fails saying `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdErrorResponseException: Either the user, 'domain\ttwp5434203$', does not have access to the 'Employee' database, or the database does not exist.`

To overcome this problem, I am thinking of impersonating the user under which the test case runs.

I added following code in App.Config file under test project.

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"
              userName="UID"
              password= "PWD" />
  </system.web>
```

This change did not worked. I got the same error again. What can I do to ensure test case on any machine runs under a specific account.

Another option I am looking to use is: [Impersonate(IntPtr)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.5#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_Impersonate_System_IntPtr_). But I am not sure how can I use this code across multiple test cases.

Comment: It depends on your client. The "correct" way is to create a new Thread (seriously) under the desired user context and then use a `WebClient` object to make requests with the Kerberos ticket - obviously this doesn't work for `HttpClient` requests, I think you can use `UseDefaultCredentials`. The "best" way would be to use a Kerberos Client library and use that to get a ticket instead of going through Windows' own system.

Comment: @Dai: Can you please share more details. Any article to code sample link would help immensely

Comment: Do you have to connect to the database with Windows Authentication? Creating a database user with proper access, and using it in your connection string will solve your problem. If that's not possible, you could run your test on server under some technical account. Create a new domain user - something like Domain\UnitTestRunner, and give him access to database. What are you using to run your test on server?

Comment: @Peska: I am using SQL server analysis service which does not allow you to create a user account. So option 1 is out of contention. I am using option two now. Look at my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now running my test cases using [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) library. This nugget package allows you to impersonate some user and its really easy to use.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void SearchUser()
    {
        var  credentials = new UserCredentials("domain", "UID", "PWD");
        var result = Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, LogonType.NewCredentials, () =>
        {
            //CODE INSDIE THIS BLOCK WILL RUN UNDER THE ID OF ANOTHER USER 
            dynamic actualResult = controller.SearchUser();
            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(actualResult);
            return actualResult;
        });
    }
```